# Smart Contract is being deployed but call does not return contract address after deployment

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodejs, ganache-cli

So I have been trying to deploy a smart contract using nodejs, but when I call the function to deploy, I get no contract address on my console. It's like the send() function never completed its execution. And that's why the next instruction never starts its execution, even though I know that the contract is still being deployed on my local blockchain network (I know it because I can see on the cmd prompt where my ganache-cli is running.
I'm trying to get the deployed contract address, please tell me how to do the same.

**Expected behavior**
Calling await contract.deploy({..}).send({..}) should return response, and after that contract address should be printed on the console.

**Actual behavior**
Instead, no output is printed on the console after this: 'Deploy function called, about to deploy'.

command prompt output stops after:

> D:/User/project>node src/deploy
>
> No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!
>
> [AsyncFunction: deploy] entered, about to deploy

Although, I know that the contract has been deployed because my ganache-cli shows this output:

> Transaction: 0x12345
>
> Contract created: 0x12345
>
> Gas usage: 1605526
>
> Block Number: 6
>
> Block Time: Date and time of deployment is shown

Here is the code that I'm trying  to run: (deploy.js)

```
var Web3 = require('web3');

// abibytecode[0] has abi, abibytecode[1] has bytecode
const abibytecode = require('../src/compile');
var web3;

if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
    console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!');
    web3 = new Web3('ws://localhost:8545');
}

let account = 'my account address is here';

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abibytecode[0]);

const deploy = async () => {
    console.log('Deploy function called, about to deploy');
    const response = await contract.deploy({data: abibytecode[1]}).send({
      from: account,
      gas: '3000000'
    });
    console.log('Contract deployed to:', response.address);
    console.log('Contract deployed to:', response.options.address);

    return response;
};
console.log(deploy);
deploy((res)=>{console.log(res)});
```

Versions:

- web3.js: 1.0.0-beta.55
- nodejs: v10.16.0
- browser: None, running the script from command
- ethereum node: ganache-cli

Also, this is my first ever post on stackexchange, so if I've missed out some information let me know and I'll fill the voids.

Comment: Are you sure that `abibytecode[0]` is an object and not a string? Are you sure that `abibytecode[1]` is a string which starts with `0x`?

Comment: You can take a look at my suggestion for contract-deployment, at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/71580/16043. You may want to try that instead (though note that it relies on web3.js 1.0.0-beta.34).

Comment: > Are you sure that abibytecode[0] is an object and not a string? Are you sure that abibytecode[1] is a string which starts with 0x?

typeof abibytecode[0] returns 'object' and typeof abibytecode[1] returns 'string'

The bytecode, however doesn't start with 0x. And I don't think that it is supposed to be, because when I write the smart contract in Remix IDE, it gives me the same bytecode (the one not starting with 0x)

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually writing comment on stackexchange for the first time.

Comment: I've had problems with it before, and perhaps they've fixed it in later versions of web3.js, but just in case, I suggest that you use `data: '0x' + abibytecode[1]` instead. Also, if your contract's constructor takes input arguments, then you should add `arguments: [your argument values]` when you call `contract.deploy`.

Comment: Tried doing that. Didn't work, output still not showing. Please note that the smart contract is being deployed and contract address is printed on ganache-cli.

Comment: I don't have a constructor in my contract :P

Comment: I'm stuck at this situation for almost a day now. If anyone can help, I'll be grateful.

Comment: I also tried an alternative to deploy the contract, but that seems to give me the same results. See here: https://pastebin.com/jAY5kef4

Comment: Have you try my suggestion (2nd comment from the top)?

Answer (score 0):

To deploy a contract a signer is required. Using web3 requires the private key for the address to be present in the node. Ensure the account private key is present in the local test node. One way is to constantly start `ganache-cli` with a set of private keys.

There is an issue in the way the deploy async function is invoked it should
be

```
deploy().then(function(response){ console.log(response)})
```

You can also switch to [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-contract.html) it's more developer friendly

```
const { ContractFactory, Wallet, providers } = require('ethers')
const provider = new providers.JsonRpcProvider('http://localhost:8545')
const wallet = new Wallet(privateKey, provider)
async function deployContracts() {
    let token = new ContractFactory(tokenabi, tokenbytecode, wallet)
    // this deploys the contract
    token = await token.deploy()
    // we must wait until it is mined
    token = await token.deployed()
    return token
}
```